# Am I over watering flowering plants

Tags: flowering

How can I tell if I am over watering flowering plants?  One of the flower plants I have looks either over watered or sick.

[image: wilted look with a non dry feel]

I will add I have small children so I am not sure if this is also an unknown small person problem too.

Comment: Did you check for fractures at the stem bases? Also, has it recently been exposed to cold, even for a short time?

Comment: Sick for sure, is the soil wet, is the drain tray in the bottom full of water?  If the top of the soil is dry then it needs water.

Comment: @JMusser my original question was How can you tell if I am overwatering plants. Did you want to put your comment in as a possible scenario to check for a situation like over watering?

Answer (score 2):

So the plant was not over-watered but under-watered.

Due to a poor assumption on my part a water mister near by had been hitting the plants with moisture in the mornings and so many branches, stems and leaves looked soggy and wet from the top but checking the soil and the drip holes on the bottom of the plant I found the soil to be bone dry and had not been watered at all, probably due to having so many of the flower pot plants hanging that I missed it once or twice during a watering session.

The heat we have gotten here in Phoenix, a couple days of 90 degrees here in March, did not help also.   And yes if you are in a part of the country digging out from cold and snow still, you can send the angry fan mail to my special round file cabinet called the G folder.  :)

Comment: I'm glad you figured out the problem with your plant. It would be fun to see a picture of it feeling better!  Also, at the time you wrote this, I was one of those snowed-in people. Now that my tulips are finally open, you've been saved from my angry note!